# Jquery Tooltip Image Preview Top-Left Placement Causes Error

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I have a small row of thumbnail images that I'm using a hover effect roll over using a jquery tooltip plugin I found here: http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery.

The plugin by default works fine, but I'm unable to successfully control the placement of the preview image. (Specifically - making the preview show up TOP-LEFT of thumbnail)

Most of my images are on the right side of the page, so I need the preview to show up on the top-left of the thumbnail. When I adjust the y or x offset variables in the javascript, the cursor and the preview image starts blinking like they're in some sort of loop.

Here's the CSS:

```
<style>
#screenshot{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
this.screenshotPreview = function(){    
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.screenshot").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+ this.rel +"' alt='url preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#screenshot").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.screenshot").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    screenshotPreview();
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="screenshot" rel="/images_no/products_large/img_10.png" title="Available Drawer Knob Options"><img src="/images_no/products_small/img_10.png" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change to CSS style for #screenshot

```
#screenshot{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:-300px; /* height of the container */
    margin-left:-480px; /* width of the container */
}
```

Comment: its a dirty trick, but all others will require a js knowledge from you

Comment: thank you for your answer. this worked, but I'm still getting a random flickering of the popup image and the cursor.

Comment: I think I've solved the problem of the flickering. It seems like if the cursor was touching the popup, it was causing it to reload itself endlessly. so, what I finally did was set the xoffset = 450 and the yoffset = -280.